# For Loop Iteration Happening all at Once Rather than By Delay

Tags: javascript, arrays

For one of my elements on my page, I want the text to change every ten seconds, and for the class to be changed. Text changing is easy, as is class changing, but I'm having trouble with my `for` loop, and I feel like I'm missing something.

I want to have the `for loop` choose a random faction in an array, and then apply that to the element. For my testing, I've been using `console.log` rather than DOM manipulation.

First, I set up my array:

```
var factions = ["Enforcers", "Reapers", "Ular Boys", "Roaches"];
```

Then, I want a variable that is a number chosen at random in reference to this array:

```
var x = factions[Math.floor(Math.random()*factions.length)];
```

From that, I want the ability to run the `Math.floor` and `Math.random` functions elsewhere.

```
function reDefine() {
    x = factions[Math.floor(Math.random()*factions.length)];
    console.log(x);
}
```

Finally, I want the `for loop` to run 200 times (I've chosen 200 times because it's far and beyond the time the user will be staying on the site), so I told it to count to 200 (`i = 0; i < 200`).  After that, I wanted each time it iterated, to wait 10s, so I have a `Timeout` function with a delay of `10000` (milliseconds). Then, the code to `reDefine` and then, in the case of testing, `console.log` the new definition of the `x` variable.

```
function reChange() {
    for (var i = 0; i  < 200; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            reDefine();
            console.log("Chosen faction is now: " + x);
        }, 10000);
    }
}
```

---

Instead of counting to `1` (the first iteration), waiting `10000`, and then redefining `x`, it redefines `x` two hundred times, then logs them all.

Is there something I'm specifically doing wrong here, perhaps with the `Timeout` function?

Comment: Do you mean that your code should wait 10s between each faction (my answer) or are you having trouble with the wait causing the same faction to be logged 200 times (Praveen's answer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something I'm specifically doing wrong here, perhaps with the Timeout function?

Yes! You're scheduling a bunch of deferred callbacks, but not actually waiting until one has finished to schedule the next.

You can fix that with something as simple as:

```
function reChange(currentIndex) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    reDefine();
    console.log("Chosen faction is now: " + factions[currentIndex]);

    // If we haven't gotten to the end of the list, queue up another one
    var nextIndex = ++currentIndex;
    if (nextIndex < factions.length) {
      // Enqueue the next faction
      reChange(nextIndex);
    }
  }, 10000);
}
```

Make sure to note that the `function` without the timeout has [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) over the value of `currentIndex` for each call of `reChange`. That is, the next invocation does not replace `currentIndex` in any previous timeout, since primitives (including numbers) are passed by value. [Closure in JS can be a tricky thing.](http://www.2ality.com/2011/02/javascript-variable-scoping-and-its.html)

The core problem is that your execution right now looks like:

1. for each item

   1. wait
   2. log

rather than:

1. for the current item

   1. wait
   2. log
   3. repeat

Because JS is single-threaded (for most intents and purposes), [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) adds a callback to be executed later. It doesn't [block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(computing)) until the timeout has expired, like a traditional `sleep` would do.

Comment: Apologies, I saw your edit before your reply to my comment, and deleted it seeing the answer to the question. Moving on; what is this more elegant method, and is ``sleep`` involved?

Comment: I cleaned up the example a bit to better show how the *next* item is added to the queue *after* the timeout calls back. JS doesn't have `sleep`, because it's single-threaded; trying to sleep would prevent any code from running and block the browser's UI (you can see that if you run a `for (;;)` loop).